# correct file path in fileOpener2 Phonegap/cordova plugin for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins

does anyone have an idea which is the correct path to a file in the fileOpener2 plugin for Phonegap/cordova apps ? especially in the iOS version
I have tried this out:

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    'examplePicture.jpg',
    'image/jpeg',
    {
        error : function(errorObj) {
            alert('Error status: ' + errorObj.status + ' - Error message: ' + errorObj.message);
        },
        success : function () {
            alert('file opened successfully');
        }
    }
);
```

if I create an `<img src="examplePicture.jpg">` tag, the picture will be displayed correctly. Safari debugger tells me that the resource wasn't found and if I try to test that in the iOS simulator the app crashes with this error:

```
2014-04-01 10:23:31.766 MobileApp[1162:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme (null).  Only the file scheme is supported.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000e95e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c628b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000e9448 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x01842fee -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x007e5a7e -[UIDocumentInteractionController setURL:] + 201
    5   UIKit                               0x007e524f -[UIDocumentInteractionController initWithURL:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x007e51ea +[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:] + 59
    7   MobileApp                           0x00030da5 __20-[FileOpener2 open:]_block_invoke_2 + 69
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x021b67f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x021cb4b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x021b975e _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0014ea5e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0008f6bb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0008eac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0008e8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x031049e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x03104809 GSEventRun + 104
    17  UIKit                               0x0034fd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    18  MobileApp                           0x00023bbc main + 92
    19  MobileApp                           0x00023b4d start + 53
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Is there also an alternative to this plugin which can open attachments (pictures, excel sheets, word docs) ?

**EDIT:**
the fileOpener2 Object is also available in the app, so the plugin seems to be installed correctly

Comment: find out anything..??

Comment: plugin's documentation for phonegap really sucks :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change plugin's ios source (Plugins/FileOpener2.m) line

```
fileURL  = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
```

to

```
fileURL  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

For Cordova 3.4.0 (and above): If you have an entry from Filesystem instead of 'examplePicture.jpg' use entry.toNativeURL() for first parameter.

Comment: that helped thanks ... now the application list appears but I still have an error: Unable to get data for URL: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.). I will test this more soon.